# Unable to retain values of golang fields when its returned to the caller of the function

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I have a function which accepts slice of values and fields as a set of optional parameters and the function maps each value to a field and returns error if any to the caller as in below

```
func Unmarshall(source []interface{}, dest ...interface{}) error {
    if len(source) != len(dest) {
        return errors.New("source and destination doesn't match")
    }

    for i, s := range source {
        dest[i] = s
    }
    return nil
}
```

and below the code I have for the caller

```
for _, r := range rows.Values {
        item := entity.Item{}
        e :=Unmarshall(r,
            &item.Name,
            &item.Description,          
            &item.AddedUTCDatetime,
            &item.ModifiedUTCDatetime)

        if e == nil {           
            items = append(items, item)
        }
    }
```

But the issue with the above is `item.Name,item.Description,                &item.AddedUTCDatetime, &item.ModifiedUTCDatetime` doesn't retain the values set in the `Unmarshall func` even though I passed in the pointer to the fields.

**Is there anything wrong with the above code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one takes care of all types

```
for i, s := range source {
        so := reflect.ValueOf(s)
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(so, reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(so)).Interface()) {
            reflect.ValueOf(dest[i]).Elem().Set(so)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything wrong with the above code?

Yes. You're discarding the pointers and are simply overwriting them with new values. To set value that pointer points to, you must dereference it. Could look something like this in your case:

```
for i, s := range source {
    str, ok := dest[i].(*string)
    if ok {
      *str = s.(string)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good but the field may not be a string always, say for example I have an int64 in my values and I cannot convert into a string. DO you suggest using reflection to do so?

Comment: @DoIt No need to bring in reflection, where a simple [type switch](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) will suffice.

Comment: A simple type switch will not suffice if there are a large number of possible types to handle.

Comment: @Adrian Thats a problem. Any better idea?

Comment: If there are too many types to realistically use a type switch, you'd need to apply reflection.